# How to save plots to the file system

Tags: r, macos

I followed the steps mentioned here:
http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/saving.html

```
xyz <- c(1:4)
yz <- c(10,20,30,40)
jpeg('rplot.jpg')
plot(xyz,yz)
dev.off()
```

and get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In jpeg("rplot.jpg") :
   unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib
   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so
   Reason: image not found
2: In jpeg("rplot.jpg") : failed to load cairo DLL
```

Could anybody suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your working directory using `getwd()`. You may also have better luck with your question if you indicate which OS and version of R you are using. Perhaps tag your question with your OS.

Comment: Looks like it might be X11 specific. Do you have X11 installed on your mac? Have you tried use `png()` or `pdf()` rather than `jpeg()`?

Comment: png() works fine, so I will not try the re-install at this time. Thanks @MrFlick

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly on a Mac, code looks correct, throws no error on my Mac, and it suggests that some parts of the `grDevices` package have gotten corrupted. Unlike vpipkt I think thas is unlikely to have anything to do with how your working directory is set.  Since that package is part of the default installation, you will not be able to reinstall it with the GUI package manager. I would recommend reinstalling R.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of these warnings on my Mac (running OS X El Capitan), I followed [this guide](http://kshuler.com/blog/getting-svg-graphics-to-work-in-r-on-os-x/). It's for SVGs on OS X Mavericks, but the underlying problem is the same; OS X does not ship with X11 support. You need to download and install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) (there is definitely no need to reinstall R).

After doing this, I ran my code again (in RStudio), but only the first warning disappeared. After logging out, logging back in again, and relaunching RStudio, the second warning also disappeared. I think this process sets XQuartz as your default X11 server.